# Wix BootStrapper exe not working on client machine

Tags: .net, winforms, wix, installation

i create a Wixbootstrapper project that includes two projects(msi/exe).This Bootstrapper exe working fine on my development machine but when i run it on client machine or any other testing machine it is not executing means noting happen when double-click on exe...Please help me to solve this isuue ...Here is my Bundle.wxs File

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle Name="E4UST_A1" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Novapex" UpgradeCode="a59e7aea-ba2c-47ef-b025-76e161f9dca0" IconSourceFile="D:\Logo.ico">

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">

      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication

        ThemeFile="D:\themme.xml"
        LocalizationFile="D:\themee.wxl"
        LicenseFile="C:\Users\Downloads\file-sample_100kB.rtf"></bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

        <Chain>
      <ExePackage Id="MySqlServer" SourceFile="C:\Users\Downloads\SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe" DisplayName="Wait... Sql Server is Installing" Compressed="yes" Cache="no" ></ExePackage>
      <ExePackage Id="MyDemoAppDev" SourceFile="E:\Development\Workspace\Express\SingleImage\DiskImages\DISK1\MyDemoAppDev.exe" Compressed="yes" Cache="no"></ExePackage>
            <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
            <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Comment: What does the log file say? You should be able to find one in the **`%TEMP%`** folder as described here (towards bottom): https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912407-Create-a-log-file-

Comment: There are two errors in Log file How can i fix these errors
````[1BC8:3028][2020-04-17T12:41:05]e000: Error 0x8007000d: Failed to load theme controls.
[1BC8:3028][2020-04-17T12:41:05]e000: Error 0x80004005: Failed to create main window.````

Comment: i fixed this error this error raise bcz i use a BootStrapper theme that is old when i remove the theme error gone now when i Double-click on exe it executes but when i click on install noting happen meanz exe do not targeting my mainApp and sql server exe

Comment: Here is the Log file 
````[1D28:3198][2020-04-17T13:23:19]i100: Detect begin, 2 packages
[1D28:3198][2020-04-17T13:23:20]i101: Detected package: SqlServer, state: Absent, cached: None
[1D28:3198][2020-04-17T13:23:20]i101: Detected package: MainApp, state: Absent, cached: None
[1D28:3198][2020-04-17T13:23:20]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[1D28:3198][2020-04-17T13:23:53]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x642````

Comment: Please try this (bottom): https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/2019-express-silent-install/m-p/1115671 - you obviously also need to provide any command line switches to run silently, just to mention it. I guess you have a config file of some sort instead?